Helm on Minikube showing an NGINX frontpage instead of a Django application
When I type minikube svc announcements-helm --url I get a URL that points me to a default NGINX page. I'm not sure why it is not showing me the actual Django application that is supposed to be there. I used kubectl exec to ls the pod, and it shows the application is inside the pod.
I have the code for the Helm setup at this github repository: https://github.com/UCF/UCF-Announcements-Django/tree/helm/helm
I'm fairly new to helm and kubernetes so any advice would be very appreciated

Helm is just a tool for templating Kubernetes manifests; it wouldn't directly manage the filesystem contents.  There's not a lot of details actually included in the question; can you [edit] it to include a [mcve]?
